# R: Get last result from console

Tags: r, console

Is in R the last result from the console saved in a variable that I can call?

For example, in Matlab I can use `ans` to refrence the last value:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

yes there is, it is `.Last.value`:

```
> 4*5
[1] 20
> .Last.value * 5
[1] 100
```

Comment: Hey, I didn't know I could accept answers. I just accepted!